# UpdatePanel and Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a form with a few fields in it all present inside an update panel. I also have a save button which is present inside the update panel. On click I do some javascript validation to check in fields have values in them and if so postback and save to Database.

The javascript is calling fine but whether a success validation or not it is posting back to the server. If fields are missing it is displaying the error but immediately posting back.

Am I missing something with regards to updatepanels and javascript  ?

Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
   <%-- <script src="Scripts-QTrack/DocumentValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
    <link href="Styles-QTrack/MenuBarControl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<%--       <script type="text/javascript">
           var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
           prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
           prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

           function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
               //Jquery Call
           }

           function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
               //Jquery Call

           }
        </script>--%>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         function validate() {



//             event.preventDefault();
             var x = document.getElementById("<%=lblerr.ClientID %>");
             var vDocCode = document.getElementById("<%=txtDocCode.ClientID %>").value;
             var vDocTitle = document.getElementById("<%=txtDocTitle.ClientID %>").value;
             var vDocName = document.getElementById("<%=txtDocName.ClientID %>").value;
             var vRevNumber = document.getElementById('<%=txtRevNumber.ClientID %>').value;
             var vMessage = document.getElementById('<%=txtMessage.ClientID %>').value;
             var check;
             var app = "";

             if (vDocCode == "") {
                 check = false;
                 app = "Document Code can not be blank<br/>";

             }
             if (vDocTitle == "") {
                 check = false;
                 app += "Enter Document Title<br/>";

             }

             if (vDocName == "") {
                 check = false;
                 app += "Enter Document Name<br/>";

             }
             if (vRevNumber == "") {
                 check = false;
                 app += "Enter Revision Number<br/>";

             }
             if (vMessage == "") {
                 check = false;
                 app += "Enter Message<br/>";

             }

             else {
                 x.innerHTML = "data";
                 bool = true;
             }
             x.innerHTML = app;
             return bool;
         }
    </script>


<%--    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DocManValidation() {

            var vDocCode;
            vDocCode = document.getElementById("<%=txtDocCode.ClientID%>").value;

            if (vDocCode == "") {
                alert("Enter DocCode");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    </script>--%>
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <uc1:MenuBarControl ID="MenuBarControl1" runat="server" />    
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div align="center">
                <dx:ASPxTreeList ID="ASPxTreeList1" runat="server"  Width="900px"
                    ondatabound="ASPxTreeList1_DataBound" 
                    onfocusednodechanged="ASPxTreeList1_FocusedNodeChanged" 
                    onselectionchanged="ASPxTreeList1_SelectionChanged">
                </dx:ASPxTreeList>
            </div>
            <div>
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            <div>
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ScriptManager >
                       <div align="center">
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >


                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                                <div>
                                                     <dx:ASPxRoundPanel ID="ASPxRoundPanelDocument" runat="server" 
                                                            HeaderText="Document" Width="900px">

                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />

                                                            <PanelCollection>
                                                                <dx:PanelContent runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
                                                                    <div class="row">  
                                                                    </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        <div class="row">
                                                                        <form  class="form-inline" data-toggle="validator">
                                                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label for="exampleInputName2">Document Code</label>
                                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDocCode" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Code" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                 </div>
                                                                            </div>

                                                                             <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label for="exampleInputName2">Document Title</label>
                                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDocTitle" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Title"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                            </div>

                                                                            </div>

                                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                                 <div class="form-group">
                                                                                 <label for="exampleInputName2">Document Name</label>
                                                                                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDocName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Name"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                 </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                             <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="exampleInputName2">Revision Number</label>

                                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtRevNumber" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="RevNumber"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                 </div>
                                                                            </div>

                                                                             <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                                <label for="exampleInputName2">Status</label>
                                                                                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" >
                                                                                 </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                             </div>
                                                                             </div>

                                                                              <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                                     <div class="form-group">
                                                                                 <label for="exampleInputName2">Standard</label>
                                                                                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStandard" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                                                                                 </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                             </div>
                                                                              </div>

                                                                               <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                                     <div class="form-group">
                                                                                 <label for="exampleInputName2">Main Document</label>
                                                                                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMainDoc" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                                                                                 </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                             </div>
                                                                               </div>

                                                                               <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                                            <label for="exampleInputName2" runat="server" id="lblReqBy">Requested By:</label>
                                                                                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtReqBy" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Requested By"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                         </div>
                                                                                    </div>



                                                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                                            <label for="exampleInputName2">Due Date:</label>
                                                                                            <%-- <input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker" id="dp" />--%>
                                                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDueDate" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                         </div>
                                                                                    </div>

                                                                               <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                 <label for="exampleInputName2">Upload Doc</label>
                                                                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fupDocument" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                                                                                 </div>
                                                                               </div>

                                                                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                                           <%-- <asp:Label ID="lblRemarks" runat="server" Text="Message" CssClass="exampleInputName2"></asp:Label>--%>
                                                                                            <label for="exampleInputName2" runat="server" id="lblRemarks">Message:</label>
                                                                                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Message" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Columns="120"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                     </div>

                                                                                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                                            <label for="exampleInputName2">Description of Change:</label>
                                                                                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescChange" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Desciption of Change" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Columns="120"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                     </div>


                                                                                  <div class="col-lg-12" id="VerifyRemarks" runat="server">
                                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                                            <label for="exampleInputName2">Verifiers Remarks:</label>
                                                                                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtVerifyRemarks" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Verifier Remarks" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Columns="120"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                     </div>

                                                                                   <div class="col-lg-12" id="ApproverRemarks" runat="server">
                                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                                            <label for="exampleInputName2">Approver Remarks:</label>
                                                                                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtApprovers" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Approvers Remarks" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Columns="120"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                     </div>

                                                                                   <div class="col-lg-12" id="PublishRemarks" runat="server">
                                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                                            <label for="exampleInputName2">Publishers Remarks:</label>
                                                                                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtPublisher" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Publishers Remarks" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Columns="120"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                     </div>

                                                                    </div>
                                                                </dx:PanelContent>
                                                            </PanelCollection>

                                                        </dx:ASPxRoundPanel>


                                                </div>

                                                <div>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </div>          

                                                <div align="center">
                                                   <div class="form-group">

                                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                                          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                                            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"  OnClientClick="return validate();" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                                                          </div>
                                                          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                                             <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnClear_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                                                          </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                      <div> 
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblerr" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                        </div>

                                                  </div>   

                                                 </div>
                                             </form>
                                        </ContentTemplate>

                                         <Triggers>
                                            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" />
                                        </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </div>

            </div>

            <div align="center">
                <asp:Literal ID="ltEmbed" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>




</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please show the code first..

Comment: Especially the markup and the click handler

Comment: Code sample update for youe help. Please have a look at it and let me know what Im doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `JavaScript event handler`, the variable `bool` only get's initialised, if the input was correct. So, if the input is not correct, the function will return `undefined` and not `false`. But the postback of the button click only get's suppressed, if you return `false` in the `click event handler`. Also, you have to be sure, that you don't get any JavaScript errors, because they also might lead to a postback.

So, to solve your problem, simply change the beginning of the `validate` function to this:

```
function validate() {
    var bool = false;
    [....]
}
```

EDIT: Maybe you want to use the variable `check` to return if the input is correct, then you need to replace the two references to `bool` with `check` like this:

```
function validate()
{
    [...]
        else {
             x.innerHTML = "data";
             check = true;
         }
         x.innerHTML = app;
         return check;
     }
</script>
```